# Monad for tracking side-effects

Tags: haskell, monads

In Haskell, we have the `IO` monad to deal with side-effects, although, it is not able to expressively track side-effects, you don't really know what type of side effect is really happening:

```
main :: IO ()
```

In PureScript, we have the `Eff` monad, where you are able to know what type of side-effects happen according to the type signature:

```
main :: forall e. Eff (fs :: FS, trace :: Trace, process :: Process | e) Unit
```

Here it is clearly that the `main` function has use of the filesystem, of tracing messages to the console and is able to handle the current process, where we have a specific module `Control.Monad.Eff` for dealing with side effects, and submodules such  as `Control.Monad.Eff.Random` and `Control.Monad.Eff.Console`.

Taking by example the following:

```
module RandomExample where

import Prelude

import Control.Monad.Eff
import Control.Monad.Eff.Random (random)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (print)

printRandom :: forall e. Eff (console :: CONSOLE, random :: RANDOM | e) Unit
printRandom = do
  n <- random
  print n
```

This is so much more specific than using just *"Hey, here happens a side-effect, that's it, no more that you need to know!"*. I've being looking through the web and I didn't see a monad complete enough to track side-effects.

**Is there a specific monad in Haskell, like `Eff`, for tracking side effects?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well there are all kinds of side-effects so which one do you want? - some of those have their own monads (State, ...) and many libs introduce some more (Yesod, ...) - but no I guess you cannot assemble them just like in PureScript - usually there are transformers and the monad-stack concept to do this

Comment: A small nitpick: `IO` has *effects*, not side-effects. A side-effect would be something evil like a computation pretending to be pure, but doing IO via `unsafePerformIO`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of libraries that define similar effect systems for Haskell.

I have worked some with [`extensible-effects`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/extensible-effects), and found it quite easy to add restricted `IO`, eg `STDIO`, `FileIO`, effects. The lack of compiler support makes is slightly less nice to use.

If you want to try it out you can find inspiration in existing effects for the `extensible-effects` framework: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/#cat:Effect

There seems to be a version of `extensible-effects` that doesn't use `Typeable` to track effects: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/effin. That should make it nicer to write new effects.